# voltage of input(+5V) is greater than the supply(+3.3V) provided for 74HC245 buffer

Tags: power-supply, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

In my design I am using 74HC245 buffers between a input signal of +5v and controller pins of +3.3V. What is the supply value I have to use for buffer (74HC245). I want to use +3.3V as the supply, but in data sheet it is mentioned that maximum VIH is Vcc. Please suggest me what happens if I provide +3.3V as supply voltage and feed input pins +5V?.
I am providing the link for buffer data sheet below.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT245.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think if you found a 5V tolerant input family that ran at 3.3V (LVC if I recall correctly), that could work

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it helped a lot in my design

Answer (score 5):

If you want to translate 3.3V signals to 5V then you must power the 74HC245 with 3.3V, because at 5V it might not reliably detect a 3.3V 'high' logic level. However it will also only output 3.3V, which may not be enough to reliably drive 5V logic.

Any 5V inputs will inject current through the protection diodes and out the Vcc pin into the 3.3V supply. Depending on how 'stiff' the supply is, this may either exceed the protection diode's current rating, or raise the 3.3V supply to ~4.4V (which would be bad news for anything on the 3.3V side that can't handle the higher voltage).

You could wire resistors in series with the I/O's on the 5V side to limit diode current, but they will slow down the signal rise and fall times - and make the 5V output level problem worse.

If you power the 74HC245 with 5V then you have similar problems, but on the 3.3V side.

So the answer is:- use a proper level translating buffer such as the [74LVCC4245A](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVCC4245A), which is powered by 3.3V on one side and 5V on the other.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you should be using logic family that's 5V tolerant, traditionally LVC. Also some "advanced" (AHC, VHC etc) logic families are 5V tolerant.

If you exceed VCC in HC logic, the protection diode will clamp the voltage to VCC so absolute input is usually defined as VCC + 0.3V. You **may** get away with using series resistor to limit the current but this is not recommended. With the 5V tolerant chips there may be no input protection so you might cook the chip whatever series resistor you have if you exceed the input voltage limit.

Comment: Heh, lots of mays and mights there. But yes, it really depends and you should consult the datasheet. Those 5V tolerant inputs can be treacherous as the cmos junction can break with 6-7 volts. Depending on application a brute force solution of adding a LED in series to drop the voltage to 3.3 may be acceptable but you then need a pull-down resistor which acts as LED series resistor as well. This is also handy if you have no easy access to LVC chips although they're not rare.

Answer (score 0):

If the input current is higher than the clamping current then you could destroy the chip. Use resistors to limit the input current to less than the clamping current.